# Angular route redirectTo with params

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a problem with angular routing. In my app i had some routes like this:

```js
[{
     path: 'myroutes/:id',
     component: BarComponent
 }, {
     path: 'myroutes/:id/:value',
     component: FooComponent
 }]
```

I want to change this routing, but the old routes must be redirected to the new ones. So i changed my code like this:

```js
[{
    path: 'myroutes/:id/:value',
    redirectTo: 'myroute/:id/:value'
}, {
    path: 'myroutes/:id',
    component: BarComponent
}, {
    path: 'myroute/:id/:value',
    component: FooComponent
}]
```

With this routing im getting a NavigationError:

> Cannot redirect to '/myroute/:id/:value'. Cannot find ':id'.

Changing the code to use fixed parameters in the `redirectTo` route solves the error, but the parameters must be dynamic.

The routes are imported with `RouterModule.forRoot()`.

Hoping this is sufficient information, otherwise feel free to ask for more. ;)

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Is that possible for without any static name. Only with params for multiple components..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem. The issue was that the parameter names in my app were written camelCase. When the parameter are written lower case everything is allright. :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems like a bug. Did you file a report?

Comment: No. Didn't thought about that. Although I haven't checked this behavior in current Versions.

Comment: Can you please post the workaround here please? didn't get idea from your answer and i am having the same issue

Answer (score 14):

Change path for `redirectTo`. You should prefix it with `/`

```js
[{
    path: 'myroutes/:id/:value',
    redirectTo: '/myroute/:id/:value'
}, {
    path: 'myroutes/:id',
    component: BarComponent
}, {
    path: 'myroute/:id/:value',
    component: FooComponent
}]
```

Comment: Ok if possible can you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue? Because I do not see any issue other than that.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but in stackblitz it's all fine. I'm a little clueless. I think I try the good old "comment all out what's not in use' pattern. ;)

Comment: Ok one more thing, make use of `pathMatch` attribute aswell to clearly differentiate partially matching sibling routes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I already had that in mind. Theres one more thing on my side, how can I put a <base> element in stackblitz? Tried it in the index.html but that's not working.

Comment: Can you please share your stackblitz?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple Guard to redirect your old routes if nothing else works.

I think something like this should work:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```js
[{
  path: 'myroutes/:id/:value',
  canActivate: [
    forwarderGuard
  ]
}, {
  path: 'myroutes/:id',
  component: BarComponent
}, {
  path: 'myroute/:id/:value',
  component: FooComponent
}]
```

**forwarder.guard.ts:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class forwarderGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    this.router.navigate([`myroute/${route.params['id']}/${route.params['value']}`]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as is: `One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren`. I had to add `component: DummyComponent` of some sort to make it work. Thanks though, that's the only solution I could work with.